# C#/C++ Client-Server application

Tags: c#, c++, client-server

I'm coding an application which will be given to many clients, in order to not allow them to direct access to my database I started developing a server application with C++ which receives the client requests, interact with the database and send the responses. but this seems to be a little bit complicated, is it better to allow the client application to interact with the remote database ? and is there any risks with this?

First solution :

[image]

Second solution : 
[image]

Comment: Just a recommendation. Why not work with RESTFUL api instead?

Answer (score 1):

Typically you would abstract the database with an interface. A classic would be odata, which visual studio can build as an asp web service from a wizard. This is restful as Joakim recommended.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_abstraction_layer

Answer (score 0):

There are various options like the one mentioned by 'tim' which can be done without using ODATA; that means creating a data layer (separate application) which will cater the requests from client and wont let them access the database directly. However, before suggesting I would like to know how you are hosting the web application?
You can still achieve no-access by client by blocking remote access to the database.
The concerns depend on your code and structure; both approaches are valid!

Answer (score 0):

if you have a C# client why not use a C# WCF server?

what you do in soultion 1 is usually the best practice.
it allows you to:
*later switch the database.
*hides from your client the database's structure.
meaning that if someone decompiles your client they wont know how to attack you.

**but** it is more complex and takes lots of extra work.

if you **don't fear someone will hack your database**.
and you **KNOW** the database structure will undergo only very minor changes **EVER**.
you **can** skip this and talk strait to the database.

but you are probably wrong.